# "model.fit()" sometimes takes Y_train (i.e, label/category) and sometimes not why?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

in some cases we do not send any Y_train(Category/classes) and the code still works
For Example:-

history = model.fit(
train,
epochs=epochs,
batch_size=Batch,
verbose=1,
validation_data=validate
)
Here we have sent only the x_train and not its labels.

But in some cases we pass both X_train and Y_train to the model.fit() then also the model works.
For Example:-

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)

What is the difference between these 2 ways and why the labels are not passes in the first case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dataset that contains both the features as well as labels, then you should not explicitly mention `y`. The fit method will try to extract the labels from the `x` itself.

For more information please refer: https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method

Comment: Understood. Thanks for quick explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when we are passing a data_generator function to the model.fit(), fit method automatically extract both x and y from data_generator.

and when we are not using a data_generator we have to pass explicitly both x and y to the model.fit().

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Please consider providing some example to support the given answer explaining show how it addresses the problem.